# What is the fastest way to completely remove multiple files from entire git history?

Tags: git

I am migrating a SVN repository with several years of history and approximately 50,000 commits.  I used git-svn to create a Git export of the SVN repository.

Our SVN repository was originally created with the following structure:

1. Each Project in the Company had it's own folder containing a Trunk/Tags/Branches folder
2. Source code for shared libraries was in another folder and contained it's own Trunk and Branches folder
3. Binary files used to be checked in to SVN following a successful build and a tag was created

After the git-svn export I have a Git repository that is just over 15 GB and I need to do some serious clean up. During the SVN export our tags and branches folders were treated like regular files, so I want to start by removing them from our Git repo while still preserving our commit history.

The only way I know of to get rid a file completely from a Git repo is using `git filter-branch`, so I created a script to recursively go through the tags folders for each project generating a command like this for each file:

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ./FS/Tags/v2.2.32/Handheld/FSFormView.cpp' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

My problem is that I have almost 450,000 lines like this in my generated script since I need to run it for each file. Running this once is quite an expensive operation, and I'm afraid that running the entire script will literally take forever.

Comment: Instead of git rm'ing each file individually, are there entire sub-trees that can just be killed?  git rm allows a fairly generous set of targets (directories, glob'd lists,...)

Comment: `git rm` does not remove files from history.

Comment: @Eevee I'm also going to run `git gc` as detailed here https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Comment: oh, pardon, i thought DrC was suggesting running _just_ `git rm`  :)  disregard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running multiple `filter-branch`es that reach remove a single path, instead have a single `filter-branch` that runs a script which removes *all* of the paths.

Of course, if you just want to get rid of all of the tags, consider this instead:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch ./FS/Tags' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

No need to individually specify files; `git rm -r` will recurse.

Comment: Going to run with that, should be much faster. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, back up.  `git-svn` is designed to convert your tags and branches to Git tags and branches, but it can't if you're using an unusual directory structure.

You almost certainly want to have a *separate* git repository for each of these projects, with its own tags and branches.  You'd use `--trunk`, `--tags`, and `--branches` to tell `git-svn` where each project lives and convert each one separately.  You could also use `--ignore-paths` to avoid migrating the binaries to git in the first place.

Even if having one big repository in the end is an absolute requirement (and I stress that this is a really bad idea), it will be *way way way* faster to redo the `git-svn` conversion with `--ignore-paths` so you never have the unwanted files in git in the first place.

Comment: I agree, having one big repository is a pain. We are going to move to 1 repo per project with Git. I should of used --ignore-paths on the initial export, but due to the time it took I'd like to try and avoid doing it again.

Comment: Our SVN repo was originally converted from a Visual Source Safe repo and there was all kinds of other junk I didn't know about. I'm redoing the export with ignore-paths and it is progressing much quicker now that it isn't adding years of tags.

Comment: All directory structures in SVN are unusual, because the SVN documentation gives multiple options on how to set up your structure, and neither is good anyway. Tags and branches should not be directories, that was one of the mistakes that killed SVN.